# Reg adding a word along with Tax word

Tags: magento-1.9

is it possible to add words `CST` or `VAT` in invoices along with the word “Tax” in the invoice.

Eg :- If a purchase is made from a specific state , lets say within Mumbai state is “VAT” and any purchases outside Mumbai state will be "CST". Can we configure the same?

Answer (score 0):

No, this can not be configured. What is used is the translation. So either you use the translation or you change the string before translation.

Changing the translation:

1. The translation is made here: `\Mage_Core_Model_Translate::translate`. Unfortunately I don't see a way to just add the translation, so one way would be to rewrite the Translate model (if possible) and make it possible to add translations. Then you use an early event to add your changed translation if needed.
2. The translation is based on the locale. You can use two different locales. Together with [Hackathon_LocaleFallback](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_LocaleFallback) maintenance would be easy. Then you implement an observer based on an early event to change the locale before the translation files/cache is loaded.
3. You hack the order/invoice/pdf/whatever model and change it there based on the state - NOT RECOMMENDED.

Comment: ok.is it possible to have some workaround  for this, i.e based on state we display as "VAT" or "CST" (may be a separate line)?

Comment: updated the post. If it helps you you are invited to upvote/mark as solution, if not - don't :-) And welcome to MageOverflow!